# How do you disable needing a template for a respond_to in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template product/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}
```

controller code:

```
  def create
    product = Product.new(params[:product])
    product.save
  end
```

The reason why I'm getting this is because I don't have a respond_to block for this action or a template file.  It is an create action that I am running via AJAX to create a `product`.  I don't need/want to respond with anything after this is sent to the server.  Is there a way to disable this so I don't get these errors? They best way I can think of is to create a `respond_to` block with `format.js` and create a `_create.js.erb` file that is blank but that seems like a hack.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
render nothing: true
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-nothing